# Why Different outputs of bufferereader and scanner?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader

I have used two file reading classes , scanner and bufferedReader. While reading the code you have to avoid the part of one of them. I have written them together just for ease to understand. Now question is why i am getting errors while using buffered reader instead of scanner class for this code. Scanner works fine with this code. I am getting exception error at parseRecord method. In this code i am trying to parse a csv, i have several classes which are using its output but i am stuck here and wonder why bufferedReader is not working the same way as scanner.

```
    public List<? extends ReportRecord> load() throws Exception {

    List<SportPopularityReportRecord> records=new ArrayList<SportPopularityReportRecord>();

    //  first way using buffered reader, please ignore the scanner part below.
    BufferedReader br;
    try {
    br= new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath.toString()));
    String line=br.readLine();
    if ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
    {
        parseHeader(line);
    }

    while(line != null)
    {

        line= br.readLine();
        records.add(parseRecord(line));

    }

    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) 
    {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (IOException ex) 
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();

    } 
    finally
    {
           br.close();
           // fis.close();

        }
    }
    // Second way using scanner class, please ignore the buffered reader part above.

    String s;
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(filePath.toFile());

    //getting header
    if(sc.hasNextLine()){
        s=sc.nextLine();    
        parseHeader(s);
    }


    //getting recored
    while(sc.hasNextLine()){
        s=sc.nextLine();
        records.add(parseRecord(s));
    }



    //sort the record



    Collections.sort(records, new SportPopularityReportRecordComparator());

    recordList=records;

    //return record List
    return recordList;

         }

           public SportPopularityReportRecord parseRecord(String strRecord) {
        String [] s=strRecord.split(",");
    SportPopularityReportRecord r=new    SportPopularityReportRecord();
                    r.setSport(s[0]);
                    r.setRank(Integer.parseInt(s[1]));
return r;
            }
```

Comment: What kind of error? What are the output differences? Be more specific please.

Answer (score 1):

try this it will work.

```
String line=br.readLine();
if (line != null) 
{
    parseHeader(line);
}
```

You are reading things two times.

Comment: Your motivation to help is great, +1 for this.